# angularjs route params with htaccess doesn't include the css file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

folks,

I am using the htaccess file to redirect for the routing with the views. Everthing works great except if I work with routeParams. I get the log but the template **doesn't include the css file**. I get this error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/angularKamers/kamersite/public_html/email_activatie/29/css/header.css"
```

javascript:

```
 app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/email_activatie/:id/:code', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/email_activatie.html',
                    controller: 'emailActivatieController'
                });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
app.controller('emailActivatieController', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
   // if I use /email_activatie/29/1060890

    console.log($routeParams.id); //logs 29
    console.log($routeParams.code);// logs 1060890
});
```

htacces:

```
    RewriteEngine On

  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /angularKamers/kamersite/public_html/index.html
```

Maybe it is the / in a routeparameter that doesn't go along with my htaccess. Anyone ideas?

Comment: easy enough to just put a leading `/` in front of relative paths in `href` to make them absolute also

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean can you give an example?

Comment: instead of `href="css/styles.css"` which is a relative path, changing to `href="/css/styles.css"` makes it absolute. That would look in root of site for directory css no matter what was in page url being used at the time. Also you should have a base tag and that would do same thing

Comment: @charlietfl thanks! only if I use /css/styles.css I got an 404 error. When I use  href="/angularKamers/kamersite/public_html/css/header.css" it works fine.   I guess that is fine too

Comment: has to be a valid web path.... anything above public_html isn't usually accessible from web. Don't confuse server file paths with web paths

Comment: are you opening page using `file://` protocol???

Answer (score 0):

This code should serve up the right content headers and gzip your content if allowed

```
# Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
```

The relevant line to you I think would be:

```
RewriteRule \.css$ - [T=text/css]
```

Comment: if I copy this or use the relevant. I get the error that the page doesn't exist unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm, do you have gzip enabled in your httpd.conf?